# Passing an Int and String argument to an arrayList index and String element

Tags: string, arraylist, indexing

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataBase {
    public ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void nameAdd(String s, int i) {
        if (i < nameList.size()){
            nameList.add(i, s);
            //string not adding to arrayList, ive probably done it wrong.
        }
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("nameList.size = " + nameList.size());
        System.out.println("arrayList number = " + i);
    }
}
```

I've been coding for about a month now so please excuse my noobieness but i'm trying to basically take a string from a GUI i've built, cut it up to get a name, and add that name to a "database" when the user clicks another button to add it to it. Ive already been able to increment the i which is supposed to set an index  for the string within the arrayList but the arrayList isnt increasing in size and I get a whole bunch of errors thus the if statement ive added to stop it from trying to add to an index that isnt yet in the arrayList.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see your array `nameList` always empty.

Because you have this line:

```
public ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
```

In this moment you create your array (empty), but in your `nameAdd` method if you pass this at the first time:

```
nameAdd('ADDFIRSTELEMENT', 0)
```

Your `if` statemnt is always `false`

```
if (i < nameList.size()){
    nameList.add(i, s);
    //string not adding to arrayList, ive probably done it wrong.
}
```

You must to change your check as follow:

```
if (i <= nameList.size())
```

Because if your index is the same of the size, you can add your element in the array.

If you want you can use the `contains` method of your nameList ArrayList object so you can see if your string is present in your array